# How to automatically update data in laravel view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a view which will show the list important tasks from database. I have a function in controller which returns the collection of data to the view.

My controller function is

```
public function list()
{
    $tasks= Task::where('category','1')->get();
    //category is 1 when the task is important
    return view('important', compact('tasks'));
}
```

My view is like

```
<ul>    
@foreach ($tasks as $task)  
    <li> {{$task->body}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

What I want to essentially do is to call the list function whenever a new important task is added into the database. How can I do that?

Comment: You have to do it by using to refresh the list view table

Comment: @Nabil Farhan: When you insert important task then redirect to list view so you can see updated view in list

Comment: How / where are the new tasks being added into the database?

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane there is a seperate view with a form and store function for that.

Comment: Are there multiple users entering tasks? Are you wanting it to be reactive, as in, when person A posts a new task, if person B is looking at the screen they will see the update?

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal There can be more than one person who can add data. Maybe another user adds a data from different machine. But I want my view to be updated automatically.

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane Yes, more than one user is allowed to insert a task. 

Yes. That is exactly what I want. Whenever any user adds any important task that should be immediately loaded to everyone's view.

Comment: You're going to need to look into your choice of JS for this. [Here is a cool tutorial](https://codeburst.io/realtime-chat-app-with-laravel-5-4-and-vuejs-2-using-pusher-d53d7f3a8086) that could help point you in the right direction. [This one as well](https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-app-vuejs/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your web.php

```
Route::get('/tasks','TasksController@list')->name('get_tasks');
```

inside your controller :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function list(Request $request)
{
    $tasks= Task::where('category','1')->get();
    if($request->ajax()){
       return response()->json(array('tasks'=>$tasks));
    }
    return view('important', compact('tasks'));
}
```

inside your blade view :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       setInterval(function(){
          $.ajax({
             url:'/tasks',
             type:'GET',
             dataType:'json',
             success:function(response){
                if(response.tasks.length>0){
                   var tasks ='';
                   for(var i=0;i<response.tasks.length;i++){
                      tasks=tasks+'<li>'+response.tasks[i]['body']+'</li>';
                   }
                   $('#tasklist').empty();
                   $('#tasklist').append(tasks);
                }
             },error:function(err){

             }
          })
       }, 5000);
   });
</script>



    <ul id="tasklist">    
        @foreach ($tasks as $task)  
        <li> {{$task->body}}</li>
       @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Comment: It is showing this error 

"Class App\Http\Controllers\Request does not exist"

Comment: @NabilFarhan , please import request `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: No errors are showed this time. 
But still, it is not working as planned. If I add a task from one browser, it is not automatically shown in another. But it shows when I manually reload it.

Comment: `setInterval(function(){ ...},5000);` will refresh your task every 5 seconds , open inspect element and check network tab , if request is sent or not ?

Comment: No, it was showing red flags and 404 errors. I checked the header and the request url was showing 'localhost/tasks'. 

I changed the requested url to '/project/public/tasks' in jquery. Now the request is passing with a code 200 but the view is showing "[object Object]".

Comment: put `console.log(response)` in success of ajax function

Comment: It is showing the list of tasks as expected. But somehow view can not show the list properly. 

Also, I have three tasks currently. So it should show three list items but it is showing only one. '[object Object]'

Comment: are you getting [object Object] in `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: no. console.log(response) is showing the correct json data. In view it is showing '[object Object]'

Comment: @NabilFarhan , please wait 1 min , there is a minor mistake , i will updating answer

Comment: @NabilFarhan , please try now

Comment: Yes. Working like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: This will definitely solve the issue but is a bad practice, you shouldn't be querying database after every x seconds,instead, send a notification to front end when there's a change in the database

Comment: @Khan Shahrukh , yes you are correct , please add some example code , so it will clear our concept , and helps to improve application performance

Comment: @SaurabhMistry  added an answer please see

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this kind of setup you may use Pusher or any other similar provider, once you signup on pusher you can send 200k notifications per day for free, you can check the limits after login to pusher. Before we proceed please install pusher's official php package

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

From your pusher dashboard obtain `app_id`, `key`, `secret` and `cluster` now in your controller/model where you are inserting the data in database add the following code

```
//You will get cluster name from pusher.com replace it below
    $options = ['cluster' => 'mt1', 'encrypted' => true];

   //Replace your key, app_id and secret in the following lines 
    $pusher = new Pusher(
        'key',
        'secret',
        'app_id',
        $options
    );

    //this could be a single line of message or a json encoded array, in your case you want to pass some data to display in table I assume you have an array 
    $message= json_encode(['name' => 'John doe', 'age' => 42, 'etc' => 'etc']);

    //Send a message to users channel with an event name of users-list. Please mind this channel name and event name could be anything but it should match that with your view 
    $pusher->trigger('users', 'users-list', $message);
```

Now in your view before the `</body>` tag paste the following code

```
<!-- Incldue Pusher Js -->
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Remember to replace key and cluster with the credentials that you have got from pusher.
var pusher = new Pusher('key', {
  cluster: 'mt1',
  encrypted: true
});

//In case you have decided to use a different channel and event name in your controller then change it here to match with the one that you have used
var channel = pusher.subscribe('users');
channel.bind('users-list', function(message) {
//if you will console.log(message) at this point you will see the data 
//that was sent from your controller is available here please consume as you may like 
    alert(message);
});

</script>
```